# Midpoint and trapezoidal rules don't converge to the correct value

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, computer-science

I'm currently trying to perform a triple integration using C++. I sucessfully used the Matlab function integral3 which yields the correct result (I know that because it fits the analytical result in test cases). Now to do it on C++, I used the midpoint and the trapezoidal rule. For the midpoint rule we have :

$$\int_{a}^{b} \int_{c}^{d} \int_{e}^{f} \phi(x,y,z) dz dx dy = (b-a)(d-c)(f-e)\sum_{i} \sum_{j} \sum_{k}  \phi(x_{i},y_{j},z_{k})$$

where $x_{i}, y_{j}, z_{k}$ are the midpoints of the 1D functions (I simply applied the composite midpoint rule using $g(y,z) = \int_{a}^{b} \phi(x,y,z) dx$. I did it similarly with the trapezoid rule.

My issue is that whatever subdivision I take to apply my composite rules, the integrals seem to converge to a value that underestimates the analytical value ($2.6 \times 10^{6}$ instead of $2.8 \times 10^{8}$).

What could be the origin of such a convergence issue ? How could the Matlab integral3 algorithm converge to the analytical value and not the different rules I used ?

I know my question is a little vague but the function I am integrating cannot be written with the usual analytical functions and I don't really know its behavior. I just know that it its gets "really small, really fast" with given $y,z$ as $x$ grows. I was hoping I could get some insight on what could be causing this convergence error.

Thank you in advance for any help or remark you could provide

Comment: Both midpoint and trapezoidal are techniques designed for one-dimensional integrals.  As you found, iterating them may not work well as a numerical method for multiple integrals.  There is considerable literature on numerical methods for multiple integrals, however; so you may do better consulting that.  It sounds from your post as if Matlab implements one of these.

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you for your comment. According to the available documentation, Matlab's integral3 implements techniques from [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0096300308000982) and [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S037704270600700X). However not much detail is given let alone an example general algorithmic implementation. I am a materials engineer not a mathematicians or a computational engineer. Do you know of any reference in the literature you mentioned that would give me a precise and readily usable algorithm ?